# Perl Find and Replace Not working with values from array

Tags: perl, csv, replace

For this script, I am pulling a csv file that includes what needs to be found and what the replacement is. Those values, `$pattern1` and `$replacement1` are then inserted into a find & replace function. Ideally this will take the csv key file & do an inplace replacement of the raw data file.

```
use English;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub inplace_sanitize {
my ( $datafile, $pattern1, $replacement1 ) = @_;
local @ARGV = ( $datafile ),
  my $INPLACE_EDIT = '.back';
while ( <> ) {
s/\Q$pattern1/$replacement1/g;
#print;
}
}

sub main 
{
# Select Key for Find & Replace
my $filename = 'stmre_fr_key.csv';

open(INPUT, $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename";

# Read the header line.
my $line = <INPUT>;

# Read the lines one by one.
while($line = <INPUT>)
{
    chomp($line);

    #Split & Assign
    my ($replacement1, $pattern1) = split(',', $line);

    # Select Data File
    my $datafile = 'rawdata.csv';

    #Find & Replace Data File
    &inplace_sanitize( $datafile, $pattern1, $replacement1 );
}   
}
close(INPUT);
main();
```

So this is not working, as it doesn't perform the replacement. Without the `inplace_sanitize`call it prints out the `$replacement1` & `$pattern1` correctly. The `inplace_sanitize` works by itself if you define `$replacement1 = 'replace';` and `$pattern1  = 'find';`. But together there it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Samples:

```
$replacement1 = '7306e005';
$pattern1 = 'leighs_satcon011016001_00753b94';
```

stmre_fr_key.csv:

```
find,replace
leighs_satcon011016001_00753b94,7306e005
leighs_satcon011016001_00753b95,7306e006
.
.
.
```

Comment: Show some sample input and output. Is your mapping file really of the form `replacement,pattern`, with replacement on the left?

Comment: 's/\Q$pattern1\E/\Q$replacement1\E/g;' try that, the importance here is that also ending the \Q with an \E, and your doing it for both.  I stole this from Eclipse complete-ant-cmd.pl script :)

Comment: Your use of `my $INPLACE_EDIT` looks fishy.  should be `local $INPLACE_EDIT`

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade alexmac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're use of `my $INPLACE_EDIT` is your problem.  You want to effect the global variable:

```
local $INPLACE_EDIT = '.back';
```

The same way you're treating `@ARGV`

Comment: Excellent, although for some reason its deleting all the content in that and the .back file.

Comment: Uncomment your print statement.